# How to remove element that are coming inside other array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of countries coming from the database.

Here are 2 examples of the input, and output I'm expecting:

```
// countries array (input)
['US','Canada','Mexico','North Korea','Korea','Germany'];
// expected output
['US','Canada','Mexico','North Korea','Germany']; 

// countries array (input)
['North America','France','India','America'];
// expected output
['North America','France','India'];
```

I want to remove `Korea` and `America` from the respective arrays as I already have `North Korea` and `North America` corresponding to those elements.

I have tried `includes()` method but it's not working as it checks for the exact value.

How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array of countries and remove a country if [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) other country [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the country name.

```js
function solution(countries) {
  return countries.filter((part) => (
    !countries.some(whole => whole !== part && whole.includes(part))
  ));
}

console.log(solution(['US','Canada','Mexico','North Korea','Korea','Germany']));
console.log(solution(['North America','France','India','America']));
```

`whole !== part` is there is to prevent a country from matching against itself with `whole.includes(part)`.

Comment: yeah this ones better than mine

Comment: @cmgchess I was gonna upvote your answer, but you removed it. Your answer was decent, but `whole !== part` simplifies fumbling with the index. Your answer also had bad variable names. Good naming makes an answer a lot more readable.

Comment: yeah i didnt realize it in a rush. i think this answer alone is sufficient for OP's requirements. regarding var names i tried to make it shorter as possible haha

Answer (score 0):

Well, if later element is 'included' in previous element's', then it should be removed. Is it right? You can get an array of previous elements with `slice()` and check whether each element includes certain string with `filter()` like this.

```
const first = ['US','Canada','Mexico','North Korea','Korea','Germany'];
const second = ['North America','France','India','America'];

function removeSimilar(conutries) {
  const result = [];

  conutries.forEach((country, i) => {
    const previousSlice = conutries.slice(0, i);
    const filtered = previousSlice.filter(el => el.includes(country));
    if(filtered.length == 0)
      result.push(country);
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(removeSimilar(first));   // ['US', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'North Korea', 'Germany']
console.log(removeSimilar(second));  // ['North America', 'France', 'India']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use a reduce to perform that action where we check if other element includes the string. This assuming that the more especific comes later in the array, ie America will appear after north america.

```js
const array1 = ['US','Canada','Mexico','North Korea','Korea','Germany'];
const array2 = ['North America','France','India','America'];

const removeFunc = (countries) => {
    return countries.reduce((acc, country) => {
      // shorter but maybe messier return option
      // return (acc.some(elem => elem.includes(country))) ? acc : [...acc, country];
      if(acc.some(elem => elem.includes(country))) return acc;
      return [...acc, country];
    }, [])
  }
  
console.log(removeFunc(array1));
console.log(removeFunc(array2));
```